# solr result grouping based on a certain query

Tags: solr

I'm trying to do some sort of "different" grouping/faceting with solr.
The case is, we are allowing the users to search by say fields X, Y and Z

The grouped counts are displaying have the following requirements:
X( documents matching Y AND Z )
Y( documents matching X AND Z )
Z( documents matching X AND Y )

I really don't want to run multiple queries to do this, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for firing multiple queries. You can achieve it using facet.pivot. Try giving

```
facet=true&facet.pivot=field_a,field_b&facet.pivot=field_b,field_c&facet.pivot=field_c,field_a
```

it also won't give what you require. 
So it should be

```
facet=true&facet.pivot=field_a,field_b&facet.pivot=field_b,field_c&facet.pivot=field_c,field_a&facet.pivot=field_b,field_a&facet.pivot=field_c,field_b&facet.pivot=field_a,field_c
```

This will also return duplicates so you should process in your server to avoid duplicates